# How can I specify an AES key in Python?

Tags: java, python, aes, pycrypto

I'm working on converting a Java program into Python and part of its core networking uses AES encryption to handle packets going up and down the line. Java's AES is initialized like so:

```
byte[] key = { 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
sKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
```

I want to do the same in Python, and will use PyCrypto, but I'm not sure how to initialize the above in it as it only allows string-based "secret keys."

Comment: Just a note: An AES-128 key has the length of 128 bits, i.e. 16 bytes. Your key is a bit short compared to this. I don't know what happens if you pass a too short key here (maybe zero-padding), though you normally should not hardcode a key in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string then

```
key = '\x13\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why Don't you Try using Jython , because You can directly import the .class file without having to re-write it .

Comment: If at all possible I'd like to stick with CPython, as I'm sure there's a way to do this, I'm just missing it...